# how to get C type definition string from numpy dtype

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

I'm working on a C code generator. **Given a numpy `dtype` instance, how do I get the corresponding C type definition string?** Ideally done in pure python.

For example:

```
def dtype2ctype(dtype):
    # < ... >
    pass

dtype2ctype(np.int32) # gives "int32_t"
dtype2ctype(np.float64) # gives "double"
```

Surely, it's not too hard to implement this by hand. However an "official" way would be safer and less troublesome when doing cross platform stuff.

Comment: As step in that direction are the variables `np.typecodes` and `np.typeDict`.

Comment: Well, it isn't really that easy because numpy dtypes can be structured (a combination of other dtypes), variable length (string, bytes, unicode) and may have non-native endianness, and there's also a `void` dtype. Do you want to support all of them?

Comment: @MSeifert Just the elementary ones having C counterpart, considering only native endianness.